# Energy Harvesting Primary VDD and Battery Backup VDD power for MCU

Tags: microcontroller, rf, low-power, peltier, energy-harvesting

Currently I am in the design process of circuitry for my energy harvesting circuit. I am using the CC1110F32 MCU from TI. I am using the [Development kit boards](http://www.ti.com/tool/cc1110dk-mini-868) that they created for this project.

The goal of this design is to have the MCU powered primarily by an energy harvesting unit we created. This module uses an [LTC3108](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/3108fc.pdf) energy harvesting chip coupled with a [CP85 peltier module](http://www.cui.com/product/resource/cp85.pdf). The peltier module is being used as a Thermo-Electric Generator and we expect to receive .37 mV per 1 delta T (in degrees F).

What I need help figuring out is a way to have the MCU primarily powered by this energy harvesting circuitry, but in the event that the energy harvesting unit cannot support the power/voltage required by this MCU, the batteries (a set of two AAA alkaline) will power the system as a secondary method. Once the TEG's super-cap/direct voltage output has achieved that level again, the batteries will no longer be drained and the energy harvesting unit will once again be powering the MCU.

I am currently considering using some basic hard wired logic with MOSFETS/Diodes, but I don't want to have to use an I/O pin from the MCU to drive a MOSFET to change the location of the power. (If necessary I could, the system is quite low power) Also, I don't want the possibility of a MCU shutdown when the energy harvesting unit cannot supply the correct voltage.

If anyone has any thoughts, I thank you for your time and your collaboration.

Comment: How did you get on with this?

Answer (score 1):

Connect the batteries (two or three alkalines in series, depending on your Vout) to the VSTORE pin through a Schottky diode. If VAUX drops too low, the load current will automatically be drawn from the batteries.

Dave

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. There's a schematic button on the editor toolbar. Add in a diagram to improve your answer.